# Using MAX() without grouping by

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

Im using Oracle-Apex
I have a table with names and salaries. I want to get the name with the highest salary using MAX(salary).

So the query is like this:

```
SELECT NAME FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING MAX(SALARY) = SALARY;
```

This doesnt work, error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression, appears. So i use this to stop that error:

```
SELECT NAME FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY NAME, SALARY
HAVING MAX(SALARY) = SALARY;
```

And it groups every different salary in one row and returns the max salary in each row, since every salary is different, it returns every row.

How do i group everything in one single big group without modyfing the tables? I mean i want this to work:

```
SELECT NAME FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE MAX(SALARY) = SALARY;
```

But with having. Its simple really, but i cant find the way.

Answer (score 4):

use subquery

```
SELECT NAME FROM EMPLOYEE
where salary = (select max( salary) from EMPLOYEE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a WHERE clause and compare the salary with the max salary of the table:

```
SELECT NAME FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE SALARY = (SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the name of person who has max salary using following nested query.

```
select NAME
from   EMPLOYEE
where  SALARY= ( select max(SALARY)
                 from   EMPLOYEE )
```